# My c++ program is not printing any output when I use my inputs

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ program. In the `main()` function, it will ask the user to input the first and last names of their friends, and the hobbies they have. For example, the user input will be like this:

```
Erik,French,soccer,END
Jenna,Obrien,soccer,games,END
Ricardo,Waters,games,baseball,END
```

Which will then output the list of users and the top 5 interests ranked by the number of users who have those interests.

When I run my program and I put in my inputs, the program prints out no output.

[image: no output logical error]

Instead of this output:

[image: output]

I tried to use the `if` statement `break`, but it still shows the same result.

```cpp
if (hobby != "done"){
    users.push_back(user);
}else break;
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "User.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<User> users;
    vector<string> allHobbies;
    string firstname, lastname, hobby, done;
    
    while (cin >> firstname >> lastname) {
        string friendsname = firstname + " " + lastname;
        User user(friendsname);
        
        while (cin >> hobby && hobby != "END") {
            user.AddHobby(hobby);
            allHobbies.push_back(hobby);
        }
        if (hobby != "done"){
            users.push_back(user);
        }else break;
    }
    
    // Print users
    cout << "The Users" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    for (const auto& user : users) {
        cout << user.GetName() << endl;
    }
    
    // Count hobby occurrences
    sort(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end());
    auto last = unique(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end());
    vector<pair<string, int>> hobbyCounts;
    for (auto it = allHobbies.begin(); it != last; ++it) {
        hobbyCounts.push_back(make_pair(*it, count(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end(), *it)));
    }
    
    // Sort by count and print top 5
    sort(hobbyCounts.begin(), hobbyCounts.end(), [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
        return p1.second > p2.second;
    });
    
    cout << "The Top 5 Hobby Metrics" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    cout << "Rank\tHobby\tCount" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    int i = 1;
    for (const auto& p : hobbyCounts) {
        if (i > 5) break;
        cout << i++ << "\t" << p.first << "\t" << p.second << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

User.h

```cpp
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class User {
public:
    User(const std::string& name);
    void AddHobby(const std::string& hobby);
    const std::vector<std::string>& GetHobbies() const;
    std::string GetName() const;
    
private:
    std::string friendsname;
    std::vector<std::string> hobbies_;
};

#endif
```

User.cpp

```cpp
#include "User.h"

User::User(const std::string& name) {
    this->friendsname = name;
}

void User::AddHobby(const std::string& hobby) {
    this->hobbies_.push_back(hobby);
}

const std::vector<std::string>& User::GetHobbies() const {
    return hobbies_;
}

std::string User::GetName() const {
    return friendsname;
}
```

Comment: PSA: Time to learn about [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: Also worth stepping through in a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Please inline your actual and expected outputs. They are just text and will be more accessible that way.

Answer (score 3):

press CTRL-D after the last user is entered.

This closes cin and makes your loop exit. YOu then get your output

```
pal moo
a b END
p d
d f END  
>>>>>>>>> ==== CTRL-D here
The Users
=========================
pal moo
p d
The Top 5 Hobby Metrics
=========================
Rank    Hobby   Count
=========================
1       a       1
2       b       1
3       d       1
4       f       1
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the code, I noticed that there is an error in the code that causes the program to exit prematurely. Specifically, the line of code `if (hobby != "done")` should be `if (firstname != "done")`, since firstname is the variable that is being read from cin to get the name of the friend.

Here is the corrected version of the code:

```
int main()
{
    vector<User> users;
    vector<string> allHobbies;
    string firstname, lastname, hobby, done;

    while (cin >> firstname >> lastname) {
        string friendsname = firstname + " " + lastname;
        User user(friendsname);

        while (cin >> hobby && hobby != "END") {
            user.AddHobby(hobby);
            allHobbies.push_back(hobby);
        }

        if (firstname != "done") {
            users.push_back(user);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Print users
    cout << "The Users" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    for (const auto& user : users) {
        cout << user.GetName() << endl;
    }

    // Count hobby occurrences
    sort(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end());
    auto last = unique(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end());
    vector<pair<string, int>> hobbyCounts;
    for (auto it = allHobbies.begin(); it != last; ++it) {
        hobbyCounts.push_back(make_pair(*it, count(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end(), *it)));
    }

    // Sort by count and print top 5
    sort(hobbyCounts.begin(), hobbyCounts.end(), [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
        return p1.second > p2.second;
    });

    cout << "The Top 5 Hobby Metrics" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    cout << "Rank\tHobby\tCount" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    int i = 1;
    for (const auto& p : hobbyCounts) {
        if (i > 5) break;
        cout << i++ << "\t" << p.first << "\t" << p.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```